# Something went wrong WordPress File Editor Error

Tags: wordpress, file

When I update a file in WordPress admin editor, I get an error.

> Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved. Please try
> again. There is also a chance that you may need to manually fix and
> upload the file over FTP.

Please help me how to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check file permission issue , that file must be have permission to edit it.

Comment: I already did file permission still facing this same error when i am updating file from editor.

Comment: which wordpress version your are using?because 4.9 has issue to edit the file from editor

Comment: 4.9.6 version i am using

Comment: Check http://theusualstuff.com/wordpress-4-9-error-edit-files-resolved/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Health Check plugin](https://make.wordpress.org/support/handbook/appendix/troubleshooting-using-the-health-check/) for general troubleshooting. This can determine is a plugin is causing the issues. If its not a plugin then most likely a server permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it taking a good while for the message to appear (i.e. the ajax request times out)?

I had that issue and enabled PHP-FPM slowlog to found out it was a specific plugin causing the timeout.